# NotFittedError when using RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Python newbie. I'm trying to run simple random forest model with 5 features and one label but when I run RandomForestRegressor I get a NotFittedError (Below) which I do not understand.

Any help appreciated...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-b670604a6f52> in <module>()
----> 1 predictions = rf.predict(train_features)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py in predict(self, X)
    677             The predicted values.
    678         """
--> 679         check_is_fitted(self, 'estimators_')
    680         # Check data
    681         X = self._validate_X_predict(X)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg, all_or_any)
    766 
    767     if not all_or_any([hasattr(estimator, attr) for attr in attributes]):
--> 768         raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
    769 
    770 

NotFittedError: This RandomForestRegressor instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.
```

Comment: Please share code as well. Guess, you are using `predict` function without using `fit`.

Answer (score 0):

First `fit` data to train `model` and then `predict`

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_features=4, n_informative=2, random_state=0, shuffle=False)
regr = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
regr.fit(X, y)
regr.predict([[0, 0, 0, 0]])
```